# echo error from php file if field is empty - ajax

Tags: php, ajax

so what I want to do is display an error msg when the fields are empty.

I'm using ajax with bootstrap modal.

So the form in the modal and i tried to make the error like this :

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['error']) == 1){

  echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
  <Strong>
   '. base64_decode(urldecode($_GET['error'])) .'</Strong>


</div>';
unset($_GET['error']);

}

 ?>
```

And then :

```
if (empty(trim($_POST['course_cord'])) && empty(trim($_POST['course_hours'])) && empty(trim($_POST['course_price']))) {
    header('Location: add_c.php?error=' . urlencode(base64_encode("you cant leave it empty")));
}
```

the ajax code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#lmao").on("submit", function(e) {
        var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
        var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
        $.ajax({
            url: formURL,
            type: "POST",
            data: postData,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $('#add_data_Modal .modal-header .modal-title').html("تم !");
                $('#add_data_Modal .modal-body').html(data);
                $("#submitForm").remove();
        window.location.href = 'courses.php';
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
                console.log(status + ": " + error);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#submitForm").on('click', function() {
        $("#lmao").submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

When i click submit with empty fields i dont see the error :\

+
I want to display the error on top of the form...

My knowledge is very small at Ajax. 
Help

Comment: How do you know that the error doesn't appear, confirm from the network tab, also, add a `var_dump($_POST)` just right before the `if` condition and see what is submitted.

Comment: @MehdiBounya this what I get in the console [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/j4w8jv) [screenshot2](http://prntscr.com/j4w905)

Comment: Well you can see that there are too many redirects, you can start by looking for what causes that, are you redirecting to the same page over and over?

Comment: Curious what this is trying to accomplish: `unset($_GET['error']);` And why do you redirect to another php just to spit out an error, when you could handle the error condition and ajax return in the original php that was called by ajax?

Comment: As @MehdiBounya hinted at... is your form `action` by chance `add_c.php` ? This would certainly put it into an endless header location redirect loop.

Comment: ^... to add to @IncredibleHat comment, it'll be better if you return a JSON and use it in your JS code.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Yea my action is add_c.php ,,